Problema al subir pagina con GitHub Pages
He querido subir una pagina a GitHub Pages con el fin de dar aviso que la misma se está construyendo la misma
Una vez hecho todos los pasos, el resultado que se subió no es el mismo al proyecto local. No respeta los estilos, ni siquiera el responsive. A continuación, subo como primera imagen como se ve localmente el proyecto y segundo como aparece en github pages


Les ofrezco mi código HTML
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Martes Guitars</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="img">
            <img src="img/Fondo Blanco - Redes.jpg" alt="Logo Martes">
        </div>
        <div id="box-text">
            <h1>⚠¡Página en construcción!⚠</h1>
            <p>Lo sentimos, esta página se encuentra en construcción.</p>
            <p>Atentamente, el equipo de <strong>Martes Guitars.</strong></p>
            <a href="https://wa.me/541130769022" style="text-decoration: none; color: black;"><strong>+54 11-3076-9022</strong><ion-icon name="logo-whatsapp"></ion-icon></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--SCRIPT-->
    <script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@7.1.0/dist/ionicons/ionicons.esm.js"></script>
    <script nomodule src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@7.1.0/dist/ionicons/ionicons.js"></script>
</body>
</html>


Hola Gonzalo, bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español. Te recomiendo realizar el [tour] para que sepas como funciona la plataforma y de paso ganar otra medalla. Para poder ayudarte es necesario que presiones [edit] y agregues los estilos que tenes en tu archivo CSS. De lo contrario el error no lo podemos reproducir

En lugar de caracteres ASCII (⚠), yo usaría iconos, pero eso ya es de gustos. Pasa link de la web para verlo insitu

¿Ya intentas especificarle una fuente tipográfica en tus estilos?

Ya he podido solucionarlo, parecía que GitHub no había guardado del todo los cambios que había hecho

o estaba cacheada una version anterior???
